# Drag to another app from a Flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter, file, desktop, drag

My Flutter Desktop app is listing sound sample files from a specific dir of my computer.

I want to drag the list tile (which represents a file path) to a window of Windows explorer, and this file being copied to this window location.

I research a lot and all I got was plugins to drag files into the flutter app but never the opposite.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: After some research i found this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30719
I not totally sure, but It looks like the "dragging out" feature is not yet supported by Flutter